# Is it possible to view all the methods and classes created inside a dll file?

Tags: .net, dll

Can i really see inside a dll file, for the methods or the classes that reside in the dll file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add them in Visual Studio as discussed in other answers but if you want to see the code and don't have a .pdb then you can use ILSpy (replacement for .NET Reflector)

See [ILSpy downloads page](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx)

Answer (score 11):

Add the dll to your project, then in visual studio

> View Menu -> Object Browser

You would be able to see the publicly exposed methods and properties 

Also you can open .net dll in the tool [.Net Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/), its very powerful tool and may let you see the code if its not obsfucated

Comment: can i look inside the definition of the method..??